# Access to 1D stored array representing 2D matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, excel, matrix, vba

I'm creating a 2D square matrix in Excel VBA

```vb
Dim Matrix(0 To Nrows, 0 To Ncols) as double
```

and then I pass it as argument ByRef to a function library,

```vb
My_foo(Matrix(0,0))
```

which calls a C++ code. In C++ code I want to access the matrix to get values and make other operations. On this purpose, I read these values as 1D array, so I created an index [R*Ncols + C], where R and C are the element position in 2D representation

```cpp
void _stdcall My_foo(double* M, long Nrows, long Ncols){

double Value;
R = 10;
C = 0;

Value =  M[R*Ncols + C];

}
```

At this point I expect to find the element having position (10,0), but I find the element (0,10). It seems my matrix is stored with an inverted column/rows order.

It would be enough to set an index like [C*Nrows + R], and access it by column. I tried this and it works, but it contradicts many blogs and posts...

Why? Is it normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map a 2D array onto a 1D array C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array-c)

Answer (score 0):

While C/C++ uses a row-major format to represent multi-dimensional arrays, for other languages [different choices were made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Programming_languages_and_libraries), so it is not very surprising that Excel VBA uses a column-major format like it is also documented in [this forum question](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/miscellaneous-languages/303521-passing-2d-array-excel-vba-dll.html).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know... Does my Matrix, created and populated in excel, maintain its column-major property also in C++?  It would explain many things in my code... And what about SAX/VB? My idea is to test some routines in excel and then apply in other SAX/VB environment.

Comment: @M.Bolzoni It is of course implementation dependent how data is stored in memory and passed around, but I would assume that the layout is not changed when the data is sent to some C++ function (performance wise it wouldn't make sense). 

Just to give you an example from another language: Python numpy can allocate an [multi-dimensional array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) with C-layout (row major) or with Fortran layout (column major). 

As for SAX/VB, I have no idea.