# Read multi-dimensional array from caffe in opencv (C++)

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv

I have a model in `caffe` that produce a multi-dimensional array. Size of this array is `[1x10x8x8]` so in python I haven't problem with this size because python automatically manage this array and I know order of elements in that. but when I switch to `opencv` with c++ the whole array is a vector and I haven't any idea how to regenerate something like python array,  I use `cv::NAryMatIterator` to access multi-dimensional array such below

```
const cv::Mat* arrays[]={&prob,0};  //my multi-dimensional array is prob
cv::Mat my_planes[1];
cv::NAryMatIterator it(arrays,my_planes);
cv::Mat Multi_Array ;                               //temporary Mat 
for (int p = 0; p < it.nplanes; ++p,++it) {
    Multi_Array = it.planes[0];
}
```

after doing that I see `Multi_Array` size is `[640x1]` which seems that it is equal to `8x8x10` that python produced. is there anyway to access `8x8` planes one by one?

EDIT: my multi-dimensional array size is `[1x10x8x8]`

Comment: Did any of these answers helped you solve the problem? Up vote the ones that did and click on the checkbox to select the best answer for this question. By doing these things you are helping future visitors like yourself.

Comment: Same question, new year.

Comment: @karlphillip, I completely have forgotten this question, I will post my answer to this question if I find my documentation about caffe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first step we need to get a pointer to OpenCV Mat object, you can do this by the below command.(I assume that data that represent your data is primarily `float` and consider probability Mat is `prob` which we get this Mat from caffe)

```
float* p = (float*)(prob.data);
```

This pointer will points to the where data is reside in memory. So for example if we want to get access to the element in (1,3,7,7) location we can do this operation like this:

```
int S= sizeof(float);    
float val = p[(
    7*p.step[3]/S +    //forth dimension
    7*p.step[2]/S +    //third dimension
    3*p.step[1]/S      //second dimension
  )]           
 //first dimension is not needed, because it is decoded in address of p
 //and if you have any higher number than 1 in first dimension you need to add it to the above command
```

So for traversing in the probability matrix you can do that like the below:

```
auto S=sizeof(float);
for (int d2 = 0; d2 < 129; ++d2) {
    for (int d3 = 0; d3 < 129; ++d3) {
        for (int d4 = 0; d4 < 10; ++d4) {
            float val = p[(d2*prob.step[3]/S + d3*prob.step[2]/S + d4* prob.step[1]/S)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the 3D array as if it were a 2D array with shape `[640][1]`, you could write 3 loops to iterate on the elements using a **[x,y,z]** format like:

```
int data[640][1] = { 0 };
int width = 8, height = 8, depth = 10;

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
        {
            int idx = x * height * depth + y * depth + z;
            data[idx][0] = idx;
        }
```

This fills the array with numbers ranging from 0 to 639.

If you are looking to access a 2D array as a 1D, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151084/176769).

Answer (score 1):

If your model data is ordered in row-major form, you can have OpenCV interpret the data as a `Mat` of the required size. Then, planes of the `Mat` can be accessed using `multidim_mat.row( row_number )`.

In order to create a `Mat` from the data:

```
int data[640] = { 0 };
const int size[] = { 8, 8, 10 };

cv::Mat multidim_mat(3, size, CV_32S, data);

std::cout << multidim_mat.dims << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < multidim_mat.dims; i++) {
    std::cout << "Dimension " << i << " is of size " << multidim_mat.size[i] << std::endl;
}
```

The `CV_32S` is to inform OpenCV to interpret the data as signed 32-bit integers.

References: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a5fafc033e089143062fd31015b5d0f40, https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details,

Comment: Why is the number of dimensions 3 ?

Comment: Thanks after testing your code on my work I realize that my data dimension is [1x10x8x8] ,however I don't understand how to access one element in opencv can you clarify that by a simple code?!!