# Navigating multidimensional array using one variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 3D array and I need to find a int in that array using a single int.

My array:

```
int arrayOne[3][3] = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
};
```

I need to be able to navigate the array using a single int like:

```
int i = 4;
cout << arrayOne[4];
```

This will print out 5.

It it possible to do it like this or is it another way to do this?

I started to code with a 3D array and I really don't want to rewrite everything if I don't need to.

I have googled around and did not find a solution.

Comment: Why do you need to treat multi-dimensional arrays as 1-dimensional ones?

Comment: See Also: [Map a 2D array onto a 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array)

Comment: You could go for the unreadable version without any intervening variable and giving only a single index, `std::cout << "4th element: " << *(*(arrayOne + 4 % sizeof *arrayOne/sizeof **arrayOne) + 4 % sizeof *arrayOne/sizeof **arrayOne) << '\n';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to be able to navigate the array using a single int like:
>      `int i = 4;`
>      `cout << arrayOne[4];`
>   It it possible to do it like this

Yes, it is:

```
int arrayOne[3][3] {
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9},
};

int* array = arrayOne[0];
std::cout << array[4];
```

Comment: it is pedantically UB though.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is it? Since array items must be contiguous, I fail to see how that could not work.

Comment: @hugo: `arrayOne[0]` is a `int (&)[3]`, accessing out of bound access is UB. So `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]` and even `array + 3` are valid but `array[3]` and `array + 4` are UB. Unfortunately, rule doesn't cover that case. In practice, I believe it would work but we are in UB world.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap your single int around the size of your array (on a chosen dimension):

```
arrayOne[i / 3][i % 3]  // wrapping around the size of the inner arrays
```

To clarify what is going on here:

- `i = 0  => i/3 = 0, i%3 = 0`
- `i = 1  => i/3 = 0, i%3 = 1`
- `i = 2  => i/3 = 0, i%3 = 2`
- `i = 3  => i/3 = 1, i%3 = 0`
- `i = 4  => i/3 = 1, i%3 = 1`
- `i = 5  => i/3 = 1, i%3 = 2`
- `i = 6  => i/3 = 2, i%3 = 0`
- `i = 7  => i/3 = 2, i%3 = 1`
- `i = 8  => i/3 = 2, i%3 = 2`

You can see that i can take 3*3 different values before (i/3) or (i%3) overflow, which makes perfect sense.

The reverse operation would be multiplying the first coordinate by 3 and adding the second:

```
(i/3) * 3 + (i%3) == i
```

---

Knowing how to switch between the two "indexing systems", it will be trivial for you to write a loop that translates your 2-array into a 1-dimension one.

---

I find the picture of a *(2D!)* **coil** useful here, because the coil is a 1D wire that spans a 2D area:

[image: 1d-to-2d coil]

---

*EDIT: Be sure to also check out [Andreas DM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446254/1899494)!*

Answer (score -1):

You iterate a two dimensional array with two for loops, one nested into the other.
In fact you don't even need a variable you just `cout` the number in the index of every iteration.
If you want to do it with a single index, turn the two dimensional array into a single dimensional array.

```
    int arr[3][3] = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
          };

    int singleArr [arr.length*arr[0].length];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(arr[0])/4; j++) {
            singleArr[counter] = arr[i][j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<singleArr[4];
```