# How to write 2d arraylists in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know how to write `arraylists`, but don't quite know how to write `2d arraylists`. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Note that `arraylist` != `ArrayList`.

Comment: note that a 1D array can simulate a 2D array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array

Comment: Before anything else rad how to ask a question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`SomeObject[]` is array and `SomeObject[][]` is 2D array. Below you can see example integer 2D array.

```
int[][] array2d = new int[][] {
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9}
};

array2d[1][1] == 5; // this is true
```

There are no 2D ArrayLists, you can `fake` it by making normal array of ArrayLists or ArrayList containing multiple ArrayLists.

```
// Array of ArrayLists
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[arraysize];

// ArrayList containing another ArrayList
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
ArrayList b = new ArrayList();
a.add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays in Java are essentially arrays consisting of arrays. Each element in the array is itself an array.

```
int[][] arr = {
    new int[] = { 1, 2, 3 },
    new int[] = { 4, 5, 6 },
    new int[] = { 7, 8, 9 }
}
```

The same can be created with ArrayLists.

```
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
arrList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
arrList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6)));
arrList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9)));
```

The data type of the parent `ArrayList` is `<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Each element in the parent `arrList` is itself of type `ArrayList` which contains `Integer`s.