# Creating a matrix class with std::vector, how to set the size of std::vector in the constructor?

Tags: c++, matrix, data-structures, c++14

I'm creating a class called "matrix" that has a class member of `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, what is the best optimized way to set its size in the class constructor? I'm using `matrix_.resize(m)` in the constructor for `m` rows and then using a for loop to set its row values(matrix `m x n`). The question I have is:

1. Is it a good approach to use .resize()? I heard it is not efficient but I can't think of anything else
2. When I use `std::vector<std::vector<T>> = matrix_;`, for example and I use `matrix_.resize(m)`, the `matrix_` now will have "m" spaces for "m" `std::vector<T>` objects, but how `matrix_` will manage the memory if it doesn't know the size of its objects(`std::vector<T>`)? What if each objects are size(1000) or larger?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Matrix of shape m x n, 'm' lines and 'n' columns
template <typename T>
class matrix {
private:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type> row;
    std::vector<row> matrix_;
    
public:
    // Default constructor, initializes a matrix of size 1x1, with element 0.
    matrix() {
        matrix_.resize(1);
        row temp = {0};
        matrix_[0] = temp;
    };
    matrix(size_t m, size_t n) {
        matrix_.resize(m);
        // Appends 'm' rows to the matrix_
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            row temp(n);    // Creates a row of 'n' columns
            matrix_[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    value_type& at (size_t m, size_t n) {
        return matrix_[m][n];
    }
};

int main() {
    matrix<double> first(2, 2);
    first.at(0, 0) = 3.3;
    first.at(0, 1) = 5.2;
    first.at(1, 0) = 8.9;
    first.at(1, 1) = 1.4;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a 2d vector.  Use a 1d vector of size N x M and then use math to translate `m` and `n` into a single index to it like done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array

Comment: 1. you don't need `resize` as you can do it in constructor of `vector`, but it do no much harm.

Comment: 2. simply as a 1D `vector`? I don't really get your concern here.

Comment: Yeah, the top-level vector is responsible for managing `m` other vectors. Those `m` vectors are each perfectly capable of taking care of their own `n` scalar elements. But you should use a flat n*m vector anyway.

Comment: fwiw, `sizeof( std::vector<T>)` is a constant, no matter how many elements the vector contains. The elements are not stored within the vector, but they are dynamically allocated

Comment: `value_type& at (size_t m, size_t n)` -- The `at()` suggests a runtime check of the boundaries, similar to `vector::at()`.  But your function does no runtime check.  Maybe you should simply have an overloaded `operator()` that doesn't do the check, and let `at()` do bounds checking.

Comment: Could you please explain what is a "runtime check"? I'm not sure what it means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to not.  vectors of vectors are a bad idea, especially at small sizes, because you want your memory to be contiguous.

```
template <typename T>
class matrix {
public:
  typedef T value_type; // expose this
private:
  std::size_t m_size = 0;
  std::size_t n_size = 0
  std::vector<T> data;
public:
  // Default constructor, initializes a matrix of size 0
  matrix():matrix(0,0) {};
  // square matrix
  explicit matrix(std::size_t n):matrix(n,n) {};
  matrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n):
    m_size(m), n_size(n),
    data(m*n, 0)
  {}
  value_type& operator()(size_t m, size_t n) {
    return data[m*n_size + n];
  }
  value_type const& operator()(size_t m, size_t n) const {
    return data[m*n_size + n];
  }
};
```

add in `array_view` or `span`:

```
template<class It>
struct range {
  It b, e;
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
  std::size_t size()const{ return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty()const{ return begin()==end(); }
};
template<class T>
struct array_view:range<T*> {
  T& operator[](std::size_t i)const{
    return this->begin()[i];
  }
  array_view(T* start, T* finish):range<T*>{ start, finish }{}
  array_view():array_view(nullptr, nullptr){}
  array_view(T* start, std::size_t length):array_view( start, start+length ) {}
};
```

with that we can add

```
   array_view<T> operator[](std::size_t m) {
     return {std::addressof(data[m*n_size]), n_size};
   }
   array_view<T const> operator[](std::size_t m) const {
     return {std::addressof(data[m*n_size]), n_size};
   }
```

and you now get `matrix[a][b]` syntax that is highly efficient.  (`addressof` is just me being paranoid).

Comment: I've learned something today with you, thanks! I didn't know that I could create a default constructor with a non-default  constructor. But why the `:` on `matrix():matrix(0,0) {};`? Is just the syntax or would it be possible to use `=` ? And what does `std::addressof` actually do? Thanks!

Comment: @oucal those are member initislize lists (not at all the same as a std initializer list).  `=` is not allowed there.  I'd start https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor -- also google std addressof; it is `&` that covers paranoid issues in generic code.