# How to map numbers to indices in matrix

Tags: arrays, math, matrix, indexing

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I couldn't figure out the math formula.

I need to map number 1 to 9 to a 2D array/matrix with the position numbers like this:

```
123
456
789
```

So 1 -> M[0][0], 2 -> M[0][1] and so on.

Then what if the positions are labelled like this? The indices start from 0, not from 1.

```
012
345
678
```

The formula needs to work for larger matrix size input: 4x4, 4x5, 3x6, etc.

I'm completely lost.

I found some answers about [Map a 2D array onto a 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array) but they're not quite what I'm looking for. I feel like I should be able to build on top of that but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Just add 1 to the index, i.e. `M[i][j] = i * cols + j + 1` where `cols` is the number of columns

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the suggestion. That is the opposite way. You have i and j and map it to a flat array index. I need to find i and j from the the flat array index.